# How to detect obfuscated categorical data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have dataframe that except continous column contains 'obfuscated' categorical data.
A few examples how categorical variables are encoded:

- binary category: c0, c1 -> 0, 1
- 3-category: c0, c1, c2 -> 0, 1/2, 1 -> 0, 0.5, 1
- 4-category: c0, c1, c2, c3 -> 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1 -> 0, 0.333.., 0.66.., 1
- 5-category: c0, c1, c2, c4 -> 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1 -> 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1
- etc.

I think that encoding is quite simple but a few caveats:

- I don't know max number of categories, but we can assume that should be smaller than number of rows in dataframe ;)
- Float problem example: 0.(3) is really 0.333333333 in CSV, analogously 0.(6) is 0.666666667. I'm quite sure that this rounding is consistent across encodings.

So I have input dataframe:

```
d1      d2    d3
0.11    0     0
0.5     0    0.5
0.7     1     1
0.3     0    0.5
```

And I want to 'recover' categorical variables (`d1` is continuous):

```
d1      d2    d3
0.11    c0    c0
0.5     c0    c1
0.7     c1    c2
0.3     c0    c1
```

I'm looking for pandastic solution. Real dataframe has about 4k rows and 2k columns, so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use [`DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with `method='dense'` for category numbers, subtract `1` and prepend `c`:

> **dense**: like 'min', but rank always increases by 1 between groups

---

```
df1 = 'c' + df.rank(method='dense').astype(int).sub(1).astype(str)
print (df1)
   d1  d2  d3
0  c0  c0  c0
1  c2  c0  c1
2  c3  c1  c2
3  c1  c0  c1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.rank(method='dense'))
    d1   d2   d3
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  3.0  1.0  2.0
2  4.0  2.0  3.0
3  2.0  1.0  2.0
```

Comment: This is good, when I know that column is 'obfuscated' categorical. In my example column d1 is not 'obfuscated' categorical. Detecting obfuscated columns is a hard part.

Comment: @QuantChristo - hmmm, not easy part. I get one idea - check if `sum`s are similar by their integers like `np.isclose(df.sum(), df.sum().astype(int))`, but no idea if working in real data.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the solution, but it is very slow... (couple of seconds per column if column need to be checked) 
Also `num_rows/2` is kind a guesstimate. 
I'm quite sure that it could be done in more optimal and clean way.

```
import pandas as pd

ROUNDING_DIGITS = 9

def categorical_enc(n):
    cat_list = [round(i/(n-1), ROUNDING_DIGITS) for i in range(n)]    
    # round(0.6666666666,9) -> 0.666666667 
    return cat_list

def add_c_to_cat_col(df, col:str):
    df[col] = 'c' + df.rank(method='dense').astype(int).sub(1).astype(str)
    return df

def detect_cat_col(df, col:str):
    categorical = False
    num_rows = len(df)
    no_unique = df[col].nunique()
    if no_unique < num_rows/2: #kind of guess
        cat_list = categorical_enc(no_unique)
        categorical = df[col].isin(cat_list).all()     
    if categorical:
        df = add_c_to_cat_col(df, col)
        df = df.rename(columns={col: 'cat_' + col})
    return df


df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
for col in df.columns:
    print('col: ', col)
    df = detect_cat_col(df, col)
df.to_csv('train_cat.csv', index=False)
`
```